# What to write in the main function when trying to create an overloaded + operator

Tags: c++

I'm just going to go straight to the point. What do I need to write in the main function of my source code in order to display 2 objects added together by an overloaded function? Here is my code for a Box class

```
class Box
{
private:

int area;

public:

// Constructor
Box(int a)

{ area = a; }

// Overloaded + operator function
Box operator+(const Box &lhs, const Box &rhs)
{
Box sum = lhs;
sum += rhs;
return sum;
}

};
```

Here is my code for the main function

```
int main()
{
// Create box objects
Box wood(10);
Box steel(20);

// Question: How do I finish the code by adding wood and steel objects
// and display the sum?
// Do I have to create another box object?
```

As you can see, I want to add the 2 box objects together but I don't know how to display the sum of the 2 box objects. How do I display them? Do I have to write a void function in the class that cout's the 2 objects together? Thank you :)

Comment: `Box sum = wood + steel;`.

Comment: Do I have to write "Box sum = wood + steel;" in the main function?

Comment: Pretty much, yes (you write `Box sum = wood + steel;`).  You display the result in the same way that you display `wood` or `steel` — you may still need to write code to do that.  You probably has some problems in you `operator+` too — you appear to be using the (default) copy constructor and a non-existent `operator+=`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Box` class should look more like this as follows:

```
class Box
{
public:
    // Let's just say the area is public.
    int area;

public:
    // Constructor
    Box(int a)
    { 
        area = a; 
    }

    // New overloaded operator+=
    Box& operator+=(const Box &rhs)
    {
        this->area += rhs.area;

        return *this;
    }

    // Overloaded + operator function, and it's friend!
    friend Box operator+(const Box &lhs, const Box &rhs);
};
```

Note that I defined your original `operator+` overloaded function `friend`, and added `operator+=` overloaded function as well.

```
Box operator+(const Box &lhs, const Box &rhs)
{
    Box sum = lhs;

    // This needs the implementation of operator+=(rhs)
    sum += rhs; 
    return sum;
}
```

Why? because you're actualy invokoing two methods, which are `operator+` and `operator+=`

Now we can simply do in `main` as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Box wood(10);
    Box steel(20);

    // This needs the implementation of operator+(lhs, rhs)
    Box result = wood + steel;

    std::cout << result.area << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @PaulLee Glad it helped. If you think this answer is helpful enough, please mark it as answer also.